# Execute one and only one request at a time in RMI

Tags: java, database, client, server, rmi

I am building small e-banking project in java for better understanding of RMI.

Actually, I have thought about possibility of having any kind of errors while executing client request for depositing money to his bank account.

In other words, let's consider there is a client who wants to deposit money to his bank account, so the client program will send a request to the server in order to execute distant method `deposit()` remotely. Now let's suppose that the request couldn't be sent at a moment because some errors, so the client will send new request because the server didn't receive the first one. The second request has been executed correctly. Now suppose that after a while the server receives the first request and executes it, here comes the problem: the request has been executed twice but the client wanted to deposit money only one time.

What I have tried so far is to add a column in the Client table ( containing idClient and password and balance ) named idRequest to check if there is a previous request sent before executing it. But it seems bad solution.

How can i solve this problem in a better way ( without adding new column in the table of client data in the database in order to identify the last request sent )?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. If the first request couldn't be sent, how can the server ever receive it? Re the general priblem, I suggest you need to read extensively about transaction *idempotence*.

Comment: I mean request 1 is sent first . At this moment, the server doesn't receive anything, so client send another request 2 , the server receives request 2 and execute it , then it  receives request 1 and executes it . The request has been executes twice. How to prevent the server from executing the same request multiple times? I want it to be executed only one time , other requests must be rejected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesn't make sense. The situation you describe is impossible. An RMI client can't call a second remote method until the first remote method returns, unless it is multithreaded, in which case the simpe solution is to remove the multi-threading. And when the method returns it has completely executed at the server.

TCP also prevents data from arriving out of sequence, although RMI can use multiple connections which makes that a bit irrelevant.

You also need to be aware that RMI has 'at-most-once' delivery semantics.

You seem to be inventing problems where none exists.

You do however need to look up 'transactional idempotence', for other reasons.